# enable rich text editor for tdo mini forms frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using plugin "tdo mini forms", so as the user can make posts from the front end. I want to provide rich text editor to the user for entering the text. For some reason, wordpress wipes out the span tags and styles , for eg : .

Comment: Can anyone help please. I referred to the thread [link]http://thedeadone.net/forum/?p=484  , though i was able to get the rich text editor, but when the post gets published. wordpress wipes out the formatting done by rich text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be am wrong, as we are not allowed to edit any core file of wordpress. But i was able to do this by editing the file kses.php that exists in wp-includes. I just commented two lines

```
// Post filtering
// add_filter('content_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');    commented this line
add_filter('excerpt_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');
// add_filter('content_filtered_save_pre', 'wp_filter_post_kses');    commented this line
```

Comment: yes, this works and made a special note for editing core wordpress file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Wordpress > 3.3 you could use TinyMce. it is easy to call
instead using

`<textarea name="a" id="a" rows="6" cols="60" class="required"></textarea >`

use

```
  wp_editor('Text ', 'dfw_id', array('textarea_name' => a,'dfw' => true ));
```